# Как перенaправить стандартный поток ввода-вывода в консоль Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build-automation

Имеется решение из нескольких проектов. После успешной сборки последнего проекта консольного приложения `Builder`, его exe-файл вызывается на исполнение в событии после сборки (Проект->Свойства->События сборки). Запускаемый файл выполняет генерацию документации, установщиков и т.д. и длится это продолжительное время. В процессе работы приложение выводит в консоль сообщения, которые появляются все разом после завершения работы.

Само приложение не содержит ничего особенного и просто вызывает различные exe-файлы с различными конфигурациями. Упрощённый пример приведён ниже:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Builder {
  class Program {

    private static readonly string EXE_PATH = 
        Path.GetFullPath(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    private static readonly string PROJECT_PATH = 
        Path.GetFullPath(EXE_PATH + "\\..\\..\\..\\");

    static Main(string[] args) {
      var files = Directory.GetFiles(PROJECT_PATH, "*.cnf");
      foreach (string file in files) {
        try {
          var proc = new Process {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
              FileName = Path.Combine(PROJECT_PATH, "compiler.exe"),
              Arguments = file,
              UseShellExecute = false,
              RedirectStandardOutput = true,
              CreateNoWindow = true
            }
          };
          proc.Start();
          while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
            string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
          }
          proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          Console.WriteLine($"By processing {file} error occurred: " + 
            e.Message);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Командная строка события после сборки выглядит так: `"$(TargetDir)Builder.exe"`.

Пробовал так: `powershell start-process "$(TargetDir)Builder.exe"`. В этом случае ехе'шник запускается в отдельном окне консоли, но сообщения выводятся по мере его работы, т.е. как нужно, но не в консоли Visual Studio. 
Пробовал и как подсказывают [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753402), но всё равно вывод в консоль от `compiler.exe` выводится разом по завершении его работы.

Каким образом можно вызвать программу и перенаправить её стандартный поток в консоль Visual Studio?